# How to delete application from sailpoint?

Tags: sailpoint

I've accidentally created a duplicate Application and aggregated users to it.  I'm assuming I need to 1st de-provision the accounts correlated to the application.  Is there a simple way to de-provision and then remove the duplicate Application after aggregation has occurred?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing can be done i.e. write a customization rule with a single statement i.e. return null; and assign that rule to the application. Now you can run the aggregation which will remove the accounts from IIQ, not from target. Once that is done, you can remove the application. However please keep in mind that this approach would be fine if ran only account aggregation without managed attribute promotion or no refresh ran to correlate entitlement. If that is the case, you can refer to the script [Multi-threaded Application Deletion](https://community.sailpoint.com/docs/DOC-3630)

If you have just created the app here is what you can do:

Deleting via the UI is a valid operation.  I think the application scorecard error is due to a defect in the product.  It's something we noticed in 7.1p4 and have not had not seen previously in 6.2.  Not to mention it works via console/debug, so why is the UI deletion different?

To delete via debug you can go to /identityiq/debug, search for object type Application and the name.  You can check the box and click the drop down (in the top right corner) and select Delete.

To delete via console you can simply run `'delete Application application_name'`.